# Azure SendGrid - detect the change in sender email id

Tags: azure, sendgrid

Our security team wants any change in Sender Email ID in Azure SendGrid to be reported.
We were hoping that SendGrid logs would capture the change of email id, and we would be able to write an alert on this. However, on checking with SendGrid support, we came to know that this change is not logged.

Is there a way in which we can track this change? Any pointers will be of great help.